# Why $x_a$ (or $x_o$) and not $a_x$? (conventions for algebraic quantities)

Tags: notation, elementary-algebra

It's my understanding that the convention of using letters from the end of the alphabet ($x$, $y$, $z$) to represent $variables$, and letters from the start of the alphabet ($a$, $b$, $c$) to represent $constants$ came to us from F. Vieta (who proposed vowels and consonants) by way of Descartes.

However, I was curious to know if there was ever any debate around subscript notation for the same distinction, i.e. $x$ vs. $x_o$, where the first is considered a variable and the second, an unknown constant.

I can imagine many reasons for $x_a$ being more popular than $a_x$; but, **does anyone know where this notation got its start? &nd was there any contention?**

Comment: Not from Torricelli but from Descartes' [Géométrie](https://books.google.it/books?id=TXopSMll0tEC&pg=PA9) (1637).

Comment: Cauchy in his [Résumé](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k90196z/f65.image) (1823) used $x_0, y_0$ to denote a chosen value for the variable $x,y$.

Comment: I see $x,$ $y,$ $z$ used as subscripts all the time in physics and multivariable calculus. But maybe these examples are cheating.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks for the flag on that fact - of course you're right, except that it was Vieta (Viète) first with vowels / consonants and then Descartes' contribution was start / end of alphabet. Edited to reflect this point.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is $x_a$ a notation for? What is $a_x$ a notation for? What convention are you referring to? In what context is $x_a$ "more popular than" $a_x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Ben Crowell in the comments, I'm not sure I fully understand the question. But interpreting it broadly about the origin of the index notation, I quote Spalt who in *Die Analysis im Wandel und im Widerstreit* [(2015)](https://books.google.ch/books/about/Die_Analysis_im_Wandel_und_im_Widerstrei.html?id=0fzWrQEACAAJ&redir_esc=y), p. 106 while referring to a figure in Leibniz *De quadratura arithmetica circuli ellipseos et hyperbolae* (p. [528](http://www.gwlb.de/Leibniz/Leibnizarchiv/Veroeffentlichungen/VII6.pdf)) claims (my translation):

> Leibniz is the inventor of the index notation. Today we would write $D_1, D_2$ etc. for the indexed points $D$. Leibniz does this differently: he writes the numbers *in front* of the letter and he does *not set them lower*. (In the case of this figure he does not write the numbers smaller [so he wrote $1D, 2D$ etc.]. But he does in other cases. Sometimes he also sets the numbers lower, but he never writes the numbers smaller and sets them lower at the same time. ...)

I don't know when the passage to lower and smaller and after the letter happened and if one can find explicit reasons for this change.

Comment: Never received a notification for this answer, so my apologies for a slow reply(!): regarding the confusion -- I was specifically curious about the use of indexed notation to indicate a constant, unknown value (i.e. $x_o$ or $x_a$ as opposed to the variable $x$) and how this notation came to be (i.e. were there other contenders such as $a_x$ to indicate a constant, unknown $x$-value). Your answer is very interesting; thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

If we write $0_x$ then it looks like a special kind of 0, since the 0 is above the [baseline](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography)) for typography. So we would expect $0_x+1_x=1_x$ etc. With the $x_0$ notation it is clear that $x_0$ is a special kind of $x$, or at any rate the same kind of thing as $x$.

Comment: Are you suggesting this is what people thought when they started writing indices like this?